# Ace editor use change data instead of whole value

Tags: javascript, socket.io, editor

Ok, so i want to get the data of edited text, send it to another client and use that data to insert new text. I am using [Ace](https://ace.c9.io) editor and socket.io to send and receive data.

```
editor.getSession().on('change', function(data) {
    socket.emit('a', data);
});
```

The other client has

```
socket.on('a', function(data) {
    /* This returns JSON when someone types 'e'
    {
      "start": {
        "row": 0,
        "column": 0
      },
      "end": {
        "row": 0,
        "column": 1
      },
      "action": "insert",
      "lines": [
        "e"
      ]
    } */
    editor.addValue(data)//Example function
});
```

how would I go about doing this?

Comment: which part isn't working?

Comment: addValue isn't a real function, i was asking what i would use instead of it

Comment: oh I see, so the socket stuff works fine then